# cant bridge vmware to Microsoft virtual WIFI adapter

Tags: vmware, wireless, vnc, bridge

- **HOST:win7x64**
- **GUEST:debian 7(kali)**
- There is `microsoft virtual wifi miniport adapater` on the host i use it like AP  which my tablet is connecting.

---

I'm want bridge this virtual adapter to guest
   for vnc connection(tablet-vncserver,guest -vncviewer or conversely).
   In virtual network editor I'm cant pick out `microsoft virtual wifi
   adapater` because of I have not this adapter in adapters listbox, but
   if I'm choose my physical wifi interface It's doesnt working.

---

pls
   help or give some alternatives.

Comment: I deleted my answer after downloading the newest version of kali and tested it myself, it didn't work for me either. It has worked on previous versions

Comment: it was not necessary. your answer helped me. I installed kali 1.09.made bridge and did everything works fine and now there was a question how to do that on this point appeared the Internet if possible.Sorry for my english(googl3 translate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different solutions to this:

1. Use a USB Wifi Adapter and connect it to kali through VMware.
2. If the above doesn't work, you might have to download and install kali linux **32bit**. 64bit version is known to disagree with you alot.

Edit: You might have to download a previous of kali to make it work.

Comment: 32?what about my 6gb ram if I follow your solutons.I have Kali 64 as host and guest in vmware.you mean that is the problem in my x64 version?

Comment: 64bit version is known to have some problems with that yes. A usb wifi adapter could solve it.